# Unified error catching with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose. For each database operation, I have code to post the error, if any. For example:

```
User.find({}, function(error, users) {
    if(error) { console.error('ERROR: ', error); } else {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Is there a way to abstract away in a single function the following boilerplate code:

```
if(error) { console.error('ERROR: ', error); } else {
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered something like this? (written freehand so check for syntax)

```
function safely(callback) {
  return function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('ERROR: ', err);
      return;
    }
    callback.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

User.find({}, safely(function(err, users) {
  // Do something
}));
```

Comment: Yep, that looks like a viable solution.